# How to select all from table and skip some row with a certain value

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to select all and skip some row.

There's some syntax error on this line, i don't know what im doing wrong.

```
SELECT * FROM ads WHERE bbookschool like '$data' && WHERE bbookname != 'TEST' ORDER BY time desc
```

**MORE CODE**

```
$data = preg_replace ('#[^a-zA-Z0.-_% ]#i', '', $_POST['data']);
$Result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ads WHERE bbookschool like '$data' && WHERE bbookname != 'TEST0160' ORDER BY time desc")
 or die (mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Result)){
require 'book_ad.php';
$adCondition = (!empty($row['bbookname'])) ? $ad : '';  
echo $adCondition;   
         }
```

Thanks.

Comment: In `&& WHERE bbookname !`, remove `where`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `WHERE` only once:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    ads
WHERE
    bbookschool LIKE '$data'
    && bbookname != 'TEST'
ORDER BY
    `time` DESC;
```

Also, set `%` around $data, if you want to search for words containing the string in $data:

```
bbookschool LIKE '%$data%'
```

PS: I believe `time` is also a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), so add back-quotes ( ` ) around it.

Answer (score 0):

Change the query for this one:

```
SELECT * FROM ads WHERE bbookschool like '$data' AND bbookname != 'TEST' ORDER BY time desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM ads WHERE `bbookschool` like '%$data%' && bbookname != 'TEST' ORDER BY `time` desc
```

Comment: `like %'$data'% ` is not correct, change with `like '%$data%'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

SELECT * FROM `ads` WHERE bbookschool like '%$data%' AND bbookname != 'TEST' ORDER BY `time` desc